# Run a script using udev when display driver is loaded in Linux

Tags: linux, module, udev

I need to run a script when my frambe buffer (/dev/fb?) device is loaded. So, for testing, I used a udev rule (called 98-framebuffer.rules) like that:

```
KERNEL=="fb0", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/test"
```

The file is not being created when the system starts. What have I done wrong?

Comment: If you run udevadm test [YOUR DEVICE] can you see your rule getting picked up?

Comment: It's strange @Matt. If I change this rule to ``KERNEL=="sda2", RUN+="/bin/touch /tmp/test"``, for example. I'm waiting for a partition, right? If this partition is loaded during the boot process, the rule is not executed. But if I mount the sda2 partition manually, the rule is executed. Aren't udev rules loaded during the boot process?

Comment: Right. When are you loading the partition during the boot process? udev rules are loaded during the boot process. Check dmesg out after rebooting. You should see udev start. Is your mount before or after that?

Comment: You were right, @Matt. My rule was executed after mount rules. I didn't notice that. Thanks very much. =)

Comment: good to hear. I'll throw the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

udev rules are loaded during the boot process. Check dmesg out after rebooting. Your rule is being executed after your mount.